# How to get the number of 'free API calls left' for IBM Watson services?

Tags: java, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer, watson-personality-insights

I'm using IBM Watson machine learning services for a university project. The services are [ToneAnalyzer](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/tone-analyzer), [LanguageTranslator](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/language-translator) and [PersonalityInsights](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/personality-insights). Each service can be used for free, if I stay under a certain threshold of API calls (for example 2500 for ToneAnalyzer). Is there a way to get the number of used API calls this month or how many API calls are left?

I thought that I might be able to find something like this as a method of the 'IamAuthenticator' object, but couldn't find anything.

```
    IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator(Keys.ta_key);
    ToneAnalyzer toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzer("2017-09-21", authenticator);
    toneAnalyzer.setServiceUrl(Keys.ta_url);
```

Does anybody know whether this is possible and if yes in java? Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: "Is there a way to get the number of used API calls this month or how many API calls are left?"  Sure.  Keep track of the number of API calls yourself.  Whenever you call ToneAnalyzer (as an example) increment a toneAnalyzer counter.

Comment: yeah thats what I'm doing at the moment. It feels still a bit unprecise...

Comment: Don't try to push your usage all the way to the limit.  Stop when you're within a threshold (maybe 100) of the limit.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I ll do it that way.